# How to load webpage from a string of html code in JavaFX webviewer?

Tags: java, web, javafx

Does JavaFX web viewer support loading a web page from a string of html code? My code is currently functional under scenario 1 below. However, I will need to break the webFile up into two pieces (top & bot), and then insert a string of html in between. The final result is loaded via webviewer. Please see #2 for my intent (it doesn't work). Can anyone suggest on how I might be able to pull this off? Thanks!

1.

```
String webFileStr = (new File(webFile)).toURI().toURL().toString();
webEngine.load(webFileStr);
```

2.

```
String webStr = topSlice + data + botSlice;
webEngine.load(webStr);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [WebEngine.loadContent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
webView.getEngine().loadContent("<html>hello, world</html>", "text/html");
```

Javadoc description:

> Loads the given content directly. This method is useful when you have
>   content composed in memory, or loaded from some system which cannot be
>   reached via a URL (for example, the SVG text may have come from a
>   database). As with load(String), this method is asynchronous. This
>   method also allows you to specify the content type of the string being
>   loaded, and so may optionally support other types besides just HTML.

As Hiux suggests in comments:

> using a [`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element) tag is the trick to load relative resources with `loadContent(String)` as demonstrated in his related answer to [How to load both html and javascript into webengine from loadContent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26488496/1155209).

Comment: oh that's perfect! The html content will be composed in memory, figured loading it directly would be a lot faster than saving it then loading the page.
Will I be able to include css/javascript as well? e.g. "<html>css link or embedded, javascript link or embedded (including jquery library) ...etc </html>"

Comment: [I just found out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164062/how-to-load-both-html-and-javascript-into-webengine-from-loadcontent/26488496#26488496) that using a `<base>` tag is the trick to load relative resources with `loadContent(String)`. I searched quite long for such a solution so I wanted to share it. :)

Comment: Great answer! Simple and usefull.