# How to load both html and javascript into webengine from loadContent()?

Tags: java, web, javafx, cytoscape

Could someone provide some suggestions on how to load the following onto webviewer from loadContent()?

http://jsbin.com/aqupun/6/edit

I was trying to do something like this, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

```
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File("src/web/web.html"));
    String webStr = sc1.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("src/web/data.js"));
    String dataStr = sc2.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(new File("src/web/cytoscape.min.js"));
    String cytoStr = sc3.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(new File("src/web/jquery.min.js"));
    String jqueryStr = sc4.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    webEngine.loadContent(cytoStr, "text/javascript");
    webEngine.loadContent(jqueryStr, "text/javascript");
    webEngine.loadContent(dataStr, "text/javascript");
    webEngine.loadContent(webStr, "text/html");
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate by what *doesn't seem to work* means ? =)

Comment: It eventually works; but you can't have ANY oddities.  There's no log that i can detect and not sure how we go about poking and peeking status values from the engine (yet).  Just persist.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to put these three files to the resources on the same level or on the hard drive.

To load your content directly from memory you can use

```
webView.getEngine().loadContent("your html")
```

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> `public void loadContent(String content)`
>
> Loads the given content directly. This method is useful
>   when you have content composed in memory, or loaded from some system
>   which cannot be reached via a URL.

Be aware though that the linked resources should be available by their urls, i.e. on disk or in resources. To reflect dynamic changes in your web app I suggest you to call Java from JS. This can be done by providing Java object into JS app: [Communication between JavaFX and JavaScript inside WebView, using JSObject](http://java-buddy.blogspot.ru/2012/05/communication-between-javafx-and.html)

Here you may find a browser demo and a simplified WebView component: [Java GUI to display webpages and return HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20135387/1851024).

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that using the `<base>` tag in the HTML also does the trick:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The slash at the end of the href is important!</title>
        <base href="file:///absolute/path/to/your/docroot/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="image.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you load the above code via `engine.loadContent(String)` then `image.png` will be loaded from `/absolute/path/to/your/docroot/image.png`.

This method is easier if you need to load multiple resources since you only have to specify the absolute path at a single place.

This has been tested with `WebView` of Java 8u25.

Comment: This sounds like a silly question (_but_) ... what is **docroot**  when I'm loading a String -- ** .. load( someText, "text/html" )**,   I am not so sure it is a silly question after all.  I have noted with the load( URI ) version, a socket is opened and _volia_, everything works.  Has anyone come across a tip from the Web Kit project?

Comment: @will if you're asking what the *[base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)* would be when you use [loadContent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), the answer seems to be `null`. That's what I get when I do `<script>document.write(document.baseURI);</script>`

Comment: In order to load relative resources (specified in HTML), when using [loadContent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), it seems `<base>`'s `href` needs to be set in HTML before loading.

Comment: Java can get the *absolute path to your docroot* for you with something like, `URL url = YourClass.class.getResource("yourResource.js");` and then [getting that resource's parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159309/5432315).

Comment: @BradTurek ... thanks for those insights.  It appears that when the base is set by the HTML, all bets are off.  does `document.baseUR` give the right value when set in the HTML (document)?  I reckon we can't set `baseURI` -- Or it will have No Effect -- since base is used to load the HTML (as is _everything_ in `<head>...`. Oh well ...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load your HTML page using the `load()` method of the `WebEngine`. The loading of the associated CSS and JavaScript will be done for you by the `WebEngine`.

Here is how I have loaded `AceEditor` into a `WebView`:

[image]

and the code to do this was just of two lines:

```
engine = webView.getEngine();
engine.load("file:///home/littlejavachild/Downloads/AceEditor/ace-builds-master/MyTry.html");
```

The loading of JavaScript source and CSS is handled for me by the engine.

The docs for the method is here:

```
public void load(java.lang.String url)
```

> Loads a Web page into this engine. This method starts asynchronous
>   loading and returns immediately.
>
> Parameters:
>       url - URL of the web page to load

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That will work too, but I have a page that is dynamically updated so I want to keep it in memory rather than saving it onto the hard disk in order to load it.

Comment: just supply the url. Try opening your facebook account from webview. It will work like a real browser... no issues